# On GoogleEngine (Java), in JDO, how do I query a list of child objects based on the id of the parent?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, parent-child, jdo

I have two value objects, Calendar and Event, that are persistent. Calendar has a property that consists in a list of events, with a one to many relationship. Calendar is a parent of Events as shown below.

```
@Persistent
@Element(dependent = "true")
private List<Event> events;
```

Now, I would like to be able to retrieve via JDO query, Events corresponding to a Calendar, based on the Calendar object key. I am using encodedKey for both classes.

I want to run the query on the Event entity and not just retrieve the whole Calendar object, because I want to be able to retrieve only a set of events, for pagination purposes.

I tried to do this in any possible way, could not figure out how to query by parent key.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few notes:

List properties in Entities (like your `List<Event> events`) are stored as a serialized ProtocolBuffer. The problem is:

1. If this property is indexed, they are limited to 5000 elements.
2. Every time you query the list, whole list needs to be deserialized. This is the **answer to your question** if you can selectively retrieve list elements: you can't.
3. If you have multiple indexed list properties in entity then this can lead to [Exploding Indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes).

If you want to understand internals of GAE datastore then this vido is a must: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8

Solutions:

1. Use a solution from Slatkin's video: make Calendar a parent (in datastore terms) of Event. Then add a parent condition to query: `Query.setAncestor(Key calendarKey)`.

   **Update:** Entity parent relationship should be used to create "entity groups", e.g. a unit on which transactions are scoped.
2. Reverse the situation: Create Event entity that has Calendar property that points to Calendar to which event belongs. Then you can simply query Events that have 'calendar == calendarKey`.

Comment: Peter, your solution is using plain data store API queries, not JDO. I actually found the way to do it. JDO supports annotations to a child object's property like parentKey. This is handled by JDO automatically, no programming required. See below:

@Persistent
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.parent-pk", value="true")
private String parentKey;

Comment: Regarding the 5000 cap, what does that mean exactly? Does that mean that one instance of the parent class can only have a event list of 5000 events max. Thanks?

Comment: To be precise: every entity is limited to 5000 index entries. Every list property element produces one index entry (if indexed).

Comment: I'm not a fan of JDO as it tries to fool developers that Datastore is a SQL database. On our projects we use Objectify: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/

Comment: @oviroa What @Peter is suggesting is still valid: instead of having the `Calendar` have a list of `Event` entities, have each `Event` reference the calendar. Note that's _instead_, not in addition to. Also, there's no reason to store the Key as a String - store it directly as a Key, the datastore supports it.

Comment: @Nick, thanks. I cannot use Key because of conflicts with some other pieces of the application (client side piece), encoded string as key worked just fine. Also, parentKey works for me, I would rather store that in the datastore than a back reference to a more complex object like Calendar. But overall, all valid points and very helpful for better understanding the GAE data store.

Comment: @oviroa What does the client side code have to do with your data model? You shouldn't be modifying how you store data in the datastore based on client-side considerations. You should also base whether to use a parent or a reference based on your transactional needs (look up entity groups in the documentation), not based on 'niceness'.

Comment: @Nick Johnson - you are right about parent relationship (suggestion 1 above): it should not be used for entity relationships. I'll update the post.